# webapi call from angular js to controller is not working

Tags: angularjs, c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api

Just started trying out angular js. I have setup the standard asp.net mvc api controller:

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
        // GET api/values
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }
}
```

I am trying to get those values in my listbox:

```
<div ng-controller="myctrl">
        <select ng-model="selectedValue" ng-options="val for val in getData()">
            <option value="">Select</option>
        </select>
</div>
```

Using this script:

```
 var app = angular.module('app', []);
 app.controller('myctrl', function ($scope, $http) {
     $scope.getData = $http.get('/api/values').then(function (data) {
         return data;
     });
 });
```

When I run this it does not populate the listbox and 
jsfiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/dingen2010/t3eXj/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Promise unwrapping does not happen in AnuglarJS 1.2.x version. I believe your code should do something like

```
     $http.get('/api/values').then(function (data) {
         $scope.values=data;
     });
```

And in your html

```
        <select ng-model="selectedValue" ng-options="val for val in values">
            <option value="">Select</option>
        </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your use case above, had you of chosen to chain your `get` call with the `success` method instead, then `data` would be what you expect it to be (i.e. the data returned by your API).

But, since you are using the `then` method, the argument fed to the callback is actually a promise object, and the data you want can be accessed using the `data` property.

```
 $scope.getData = $http.get('/api/values').then(function (promise) {
     return promise.data;
 });
```